# SQLAlchemy Updating multiple fields on multiple objects with a single database query

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a list of Category model objects that have their name, parent_id and archive fields changed and I need to update those objects in the database. Now I do it in a loop - I get an object from the database by id, set new field values and update the object. This is not optimal and I would like to know how can I do this with a single database query?

```
def update(id: int, instance: Category) -> None:
        instance.id = id
        instance = session.merge(instance)
        session.commit()
        return instance

def update_categories(categorues_to_update: list[Category]):
    for category_to_update in categories_to_update:
        category = session.execute(select(Category).where(Category.id==category_to_update.id))
        category.name = category_to_update.name
        category.parent_id = category_to_update.parent_id
        category.archive = category_to_update.archive
        update(category.id, category)
```

Comment: do you need the instances or just want to update?

Comment: @python_user just want to update in db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement with `update` like so, you still use a loop, but the query is made only once after the loop is completed (one query to db)

```py
from sqlalchemy import update, case
case_1 = []
case_2 = []
case_3 = []
for category_to_update in categories_to_update:
    case_1.append((Category.id == category_to_update.id, category_to_update.name))
    case_2.append((Category.id == category_to_update.id, category_to_update.parent_id))
    case_3.append((Category.id == category_to_update.id, category_to_update.archive))
statement = update(Category).values(
    name=case(*case_1, else_=Category.name),
    parent_id=case(*case_2, else_=Category.parent_id),
    archive=case(*case_3, else_=Category.archive),
)
session.execute(statement)
```

Comment: It works, thanks! And why is this variable needed in each list? Category.id == category_to_update.id

Comment: the first element `Category.id == category_to_update.id` is the condition it has to match, in your case it has to match based on`.id`, the second element `category_to_update.xxx` (xxx = name, parent_id, archive) is the value to use if that condition is matched, does it make sense @Etozeigor

Comment: What if I know for sure that category_to_update contains both name and parent_id and archive? Is it possible to do without Category.id == category_to_update.id and somehow simplify the code?

Comment: I didn't understand that, can you explain?  fwiw, each `case` is one column you have to update, what this code does is basically construct a case statement that tells, "if the id matches a certain value then update column x for that match", you do this for 3 columns you want to update @Etozeigor, you have a `where` condition in your code, that is exactly what this is, but not used in `where` but inside a `case` statement